# How to stop layer/variable duplication after qgis plugin restart?

Tags: python, qgis

I just started my first QGIS-Plugin. One part will be, to connect a button to a function which creates a point-vector-layer.
I created the base-plugin with the Plugin-Builder and started with a memory-layer:

This is how my custom part of the "run(self)" function looks like:

```
        self.dockwidget.createShape.clicked.connect(self.createShp)

def createShp(self):
      self.pointLayer = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "test", "memory")
      self.pointLayer.startEditing()
      self.layerData = self.pointLayer.dataProvider()
      self.layerData.addAttributes([ QgsField("ID", QVariant.String), QgsField("testfield", QVariant.String)])
      self.pointLayer.commitChanges()
      QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(self.pointLayer)
```

The code works and creates a vector-layer in the memory and adds that to the map.

The Problem I encountered is, that every time I close my Plugin and restart it, one additional vector-layer is created and added to the map when I click the button. That only resets if I restart QGIS.

I tried to remove the layer from the QgsMapLayerRegistry when the onClosePlugin(self)-function runs. But that only deletes one visible layer.
My guess is, that every time the plugin is started and the button is clicked, one additional vector-layer is added to the "self.pointLayer" variable and then transferred to the QgsMapLayerRegistry. But why not at every click? why only after plugin restart?
I wasn't able to solve this problem and I hope for some advice here.

Best regards

Comment: You need disconnect the UI signals.Try writing `self.dockwidget.createShape.clicked.disconnect(self.createShp)` in your unload method.

Comment: And the connect Signal put in a `initGui(self):` method ,not in a `run(self):`